# Exceptions in tomcat log file

Tags: java, tomcat

Actually while i am configuring tomcat server 8.5 in my eclipse i am getting following error

***An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V***

Could you please help me to solve this!!

Comment: Did you do any research on your own for this? It's not good to just dump your log file into the site and expect someone to resolve the issues.

Comment: You have to at least explain what your problem is, and what (if anything) you have done to rectify the issue.

Comment: Now in my localhost 8080 apache is running successfully but in eclipse while configuring the apache server it is showing                   An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

Answer (score -1):

Check your `server.xml` for any formatting/syntax error.

Comment: Downvoted. You could have posted this suggestion as a comment, but it doesn't reach the threshold of being an answer.

Comment: @skomisa right, but I'm suggesting anything on a question rated -8, which means we're likely to all waste time on it.